# How to access json coming from GET operation in Angular2

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a method, that allows me to get data

```
onGet() {
    this._httpService.getCurrent(this.model.user_email)
      .subscribe(
        data => this.getData = JSON.stringify(data),
        error => alert(error),
        () => console.log('Finished')
      );
  }
```

I receive a Json, that gives me a number, like
`{current: '1', some_other_data: 'data1'}` or
`{current: '2', some_other_data: 'data1'}` or
`{current: '3', some_other_data: 'data1'}` etc

I get the data, but I can't use it. 
I need to use data for my Router, something like (it doesn't work of course, just some kind of pseudocode)

```
 goAhead() {
if(current = 1){
    this.router.navigate( ['page-1'] );
} else if (current = 2){
    this.router.navigate( ['page-2'] );
}
  }
```

In my `goAhead` method I can't see new value of getData, it is undefined. 
How could I fix this?

Comment: why are you stringifying it? and what is `current` supposed to be? is it meant to be `this.getData.current`? But anyway, don't stringify it if you want it as an object

Comment: AJT_82 Without stringifying I get an error **Type void is not assignable to type string**

Comment: Well somewhere you are not assigning/returning *something* that expects *something* (string). It isn't clear based on this code. How are these two snippets related to each other, when should you be routing, when do you retrieve data? Not enough information ;)

Comment: give us more information like where  are you calling onGet method,when the goAhead method is called.

Comment: Is `getData` a string?

Comment: @vikk I have a button, which have to call these two methods, one after another. So, I guess, I have to call onGet in which later I call goAhead, like onGet() {get json; this.goAhead();}

Comment: try the code i posted,if it doesnt work then please paste your service code and exact json response  as well

Comment: please find the edited code now ..there was a mistake in the previous code i posted .

Answer (score 0):

Okay assuming you are using goahead function in the component and calling a service that returns the result as received,change your code to following

```
onGet() {
    this._httpService.getCurrent(this.model.user_email)
      .subscribe(
        data => this.getData = data.json();
        error => alert(error),
        () => console.log('Finished')
      );
  }
```

and assuming goahead function is in the same component and is not an array,then

```
 goAhead() {
if(this.getData.current == 1){
    this.router.navigate( ['page-1'] );
} else if (this.getData.current == 2){
    this.router.navigate( ['page-2'] );
}
  }
```

should do the trick